# How Do I get a Random Variable Based on Time in Java

Tags: java, random, int

I am trying to make a program that picks random numbers between 1 and 0. However, when I run the program, I get the same output over and over again (20 times!). How might I go about fixing this? I have heard that `Math.random()` is more biased than `random()`.

This is my code:

```
public class Startup {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double match = Math.random();

        for(int i = 0; i <= 20; i++){
            if(match < 0.05){
                System.out.println("a");
            }
            else if(0.05 <= match && match <= 0.1){
                System.out.println("b");
            }
            else if(0.1 < match && match <= 0.15){
                System.out.println("c");
            }
            else if(0.15 < match && match <= 0.2){
                System.out.println("d");
            }
            else if(0.2 < match && match <= 0.25){
                System.out.println("e");
            }
            else if(0.25 < match && match <= 0.3){
                System.out.println("f");
            }
            else if(0.3 < match && match <= 0.35){
                System.out.println("g");
            }
            else if(0.35 < match && match <= 0.4){
                System.out.println("h");
            }
            else if(0.35 < match && match <= 0.4){
                System.out.println("i");
            }
            else if(0.4 < match && match <= 0.45){
                System.out.println("j");
            }
            else if(0.45 < match && match <= 0.5){
                System.out.println("k");
            }
            else if(0.5 < match && match <= 0.55){
                System.out.println("l");
            }
            else if(0.55 < match && match <= 0.6){
                System.out.println("m");
            }
            else if(0.6 < match && match <= 0.65){
                System.out.println("n");
            }
            else if(0.65 < match && match <= 0.7){
                System.out.println("o");
            }
            else if(0.7 < match && match <= 0.75){
                System.out.println("p");
            }
            else if(0.75 < match && match <= 0.8){
                System.out.println("q");
            }
            else if(0.8 < match && match <= 0.85){
                System.out.println("r");
            }
            else if(0.85 < match && match <= 0.9){
                System.out.println("s");
            }
            else if(0.9 < match && match <= 0.95){
                System.out.println("t");
            }
            else if(0.95 < match && match <= 1){
                System.out.println("u");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: _However, when I run the program, I get the same output over and over again (20 times!)_ I don't believe you.

Comment: Actually, I ran it, and it returned 1 twenty-one times, but that isn't the focus of my question.

Comment: I guess you can [never be sure](http://dilbert.com/strip/2001-10-25). My guess is [fair dice roll](http://www.xkcd.com/221/).

Comment: double match = Math.random(); is only being called once since it is outside the for loop.

Answer (score -1):

You could try this, it will give you output for one time and output will vary from one time to another time.

```
class Startup {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double match = Math.random();


            if(match < 0.05){
                System.out.println("a");
            }
            else if(0.05 <= match && match <= 0.1){
                System.out.println("b");
            }
            else if(0.1 < match && match <= 0.15){
                System.out.println("c");
            }
            else if(0.15 < match && match <= 0.2){
                System.out.println("d");
            }
            else if(0.2 < match && match <= 0.25){
                System.out.println("e");
            }
            else if(0.25 < match && match <= 0.3){
                System.out.println("f");
            }
            else if(0.3 < match && match <= 0.35){
                System.out.println("g");
            }
            else if(0.35 < match && match <= 0.4){
                System.out.println("h");
            }
            else if(0.35 < match && match <= 0.4){
                System.out.println("i");
            }
            else if(0.4 < match && match <= 0.45){
                System.out.println("j");
            }
            else if(0.45 < match && match <= 0.5){
                System.out.println("k");
            }
            else if(0.5 < match && match <= 0.55){
                System.out.println("l");
            }
            else if(0.55 < match && match <= 0.6){
                System.out.println("m");
            }
            else if(0.6 < match && match <= 0.65){
                System.out.println("n");
            }
            else if(0.65 < match && match <= 0.7){
                System.out.println("o");
            }
            else if(0.7 < match && match <= 0.75){
                System.out.println("p");
            }
            else if(0.75 < match && match <= 0.8){
                System.out.println("q");
            }
            else if(0.8 < match && match <= 0.85){
                System.out.println("r");
            }
            else if(0.85 < match && match <= 0.9){
                System.out.println("s");
            }
            else if(0.9 < match && match <= 0.95){
                System.out.println("t");
            }
            else if(0.95 < match && match <= 1){
                System.out.println("u");
            }

    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It's very easy with a nested `for` loop. No need to waste time and effort using more `if-else` statements. Refer following code.

```
public class Startup {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double random;
        char[] chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstu".toCharArray();

        for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++) {
            random = Math.random();
            for (int i = 0; i <= 20; i++) {
                if (random >= i * 0.05 && random < (i + 1) * 0.05) {
                    System.out.println(chars[i]);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Update:** Code is modified to get 20 random numbers. Last edition had only one random number and single output. Question was unclear to me when it needs 20 different outputs.

Comment: is there any problem with this code. i am well tested and it's working fine.

Answer (score -1):

As pointed out in the comments, you get the random value once, and then read the same value 20 times inside the loop. Obviously the value won't change that way.

The obvious fix to read a different random value on every loop iteration is to move the `match` declaration and assignment ***inside*** the loop body.

```
public class Startup {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(int i = 0; i <= 20; i++){
            double match = Math.random(); // moved INSIDE loop

            if(match < 0.05){
                System.out.println("a");
            }
            else if(0.05 <= match && match <= 0.1){
                System.out.println("b");
            }
            // rest of the conditions here
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

using this parttern: `int random = min + (int)(Math.random() * ((max - min) + 1)`

```
public class Test
{

    public static void main(String []args){
    int min = 0;
    int max = 1;

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        System.out.println(min + (int)(Math.random() * ((max - min) + 1)));
     }
}
```